# How to configure SSL in WSO2 APIM Analytic 3.0.0?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I'm using WSO2 APIM ( [source am](https://hub.docker.com/r/wso2/wso2am)) and WSO2 APIM Analytic ( [source worker](https://hub.docker.com/r/wso2/wso2am-analytics-worker) and [source dashboard](https://hub.docker.com/r/wso2/wso2am-analytics-dashboard)) on Docker.

I'm searching solution to change certificate of WSO2 Analytic.

I know that this new version, we need configure deployment.yaml file. But it seems hard to understand. And I dont know which element I need to configure. There are two suspicious elements, which have keystore property:

```
databridge.config:
    # No of worker threads to consume events
    # THIS IS A MANDATORY FIELD
  workerThreads: 10
    # Maximum amount of messages that can be queued internally in MB
    # THIS IS A MANDATORY FIELD
  maxEventBufferCapacity: 10000000
    # Queue size; the maximum number of events that can be stored in the queue
    # THIS IS A MANDATORY FIELD
  eventBufferSize: 2000
    # Keystore file path
    # THIS IS A MANDATORY FIELD
  keyStoreLocation : ${sys:carbon.home}/resources/security/wso2carbon.jks
    # Keystore password
    # THIS IS A MANDATORY FIELD
  keyStorePassword : wso2carbon
    # Session Timeout value in mins
    # THIS IS A MANDATORY FIELD
  clientTimeoutMin: 30
    # Data receiver configurations
    # THIS IS A MANDATORY FIELD
  dataReceivers:
  -
      # Data receiver configuration
    dataReceiver:
        # Data receiver type
        # THIS IS A MANDATORY FIELD
      type: Thrift
        # Data receiver properties
      properties:
        tcpPort: '7611'
        sslPort: '7711'

  -
      # Data receiver configuration
    dataReceiver:
        # Data receiver type
        # THIS IS A MANDATORY FIELD
      type: Binary
        # Data receiver properties
      properties:
        tcpPort: '9611'
        sslPort: '9711'
        tcpReceiverThreadPoolSize: '100'
        sslReceiverThreadPoolSize: '100'
        hostName: 0.0.0.0
```

and

```
 wso2.transport.http:
  transportProperties:
    - name: "server.bootstrap.socket.timeout"
      value: 60
    - name: "client.bootstrap.socket.timeout"
      value: 60
    - name: "latency.metrics.enabled"
      value: true

  listenerConfigurations:
    - id: "default-https"
      host: "0.0.0.0"
      port: 9643
      scheme: https
      keyStoreFile: "${carbon.home}/resources/security/wso2carbon.jks"
      keyStorePassword: wso2carbon
      certPass: wso2carbon
```

So what exactly should I configure?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following.

1. Create a new certificate
2. Create a new keystore called wso2carbon.jks.
3. Replace the new keystore wso2carbon.jks with the existing keystore that resides in wso2am-analytics-3.0.0/resources/security location.
4. Add the new cert to the clien-trustore.jks file that resides in wso2am-analytics-3.0.0/resources/security location.

You can find the documentation in https://docs.wso2.com/display/ADMIN44x/Creating+New+Keystores

Comment: I dont think this is the root resolving. Because, if we replace wso2carbon.jks, it will effect on something not just for SSL.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to achieve it as follows.

1) For worker profile

```
databridge.config:
&
listenerConfigurations :   id: "msf4j-https"
```

2) For dashboard profile

```
listenerConfigurations: id: "default-https"
```